# Informatica powercenter

Tags: sql-server, informatica

I have a flat file as source which contains two columns named "Event begin time"  and "event end time" that has both date and time in it .
How can I calculate MOU(minutes of usage) for it using 
Informatica.
Please help me..

Thanks
Vinay

Comment: Can you be more specific in terms of code? What have you tried? Can you provide us with a "minimal complete verifiable example?"

Answer (score 1):

The `DATE_DIFF` function can be used for calculating the time duration:

```
DATE_DIFF( Event_End_Time, Event_Begin_Time, MI)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need Informatica to know that each of the 2 dates from the flat file are indeed dates and the format from the INCOMING date fields, you will do this by passing them to an expression transformaton i.e. if they are in 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' then the expression to turn them into date/time in informatica will be TO_DATE (EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') (You'll have to do same for event end time... I've used name with underscores instead of spaces as informatica doesnt allow spaces in port names)

Then you'll use datediff to subtract the begin time from the end time... lets say you named the 2 variable ports which contain the above calculation as v_BEGIN and v_END, the calculation for minutes will be DATE_DIFF(v_BEGIN, v_END, 'MI')

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of achieving it : 
Consider T1 and T2 as Start time and end time (Ensure that,both are in DATE Format).

In variable calculate T2-T1 : This will give you difference in days.
Multiply it by ( 24*60 ) will give you number of minutes.
So,  24*60*(T2-T1).